# Slick Slider with Visual Composer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, slick.js

I want to use slick slider with sync option in my theme. I added js&css files in my functions.php. I created row in VC, then 2 columns. In first column I have 3 paragraphs. On second column I have 3 images. I want to scroll paragraphs and the change images. This is how it looks now

[image]

in my custom js I added something like this

```
 $('.slider-for').slick({
   slidesToShow: 1,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   arrows: false,
   fade: true,
   asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
 });
 $('.slider-nav').slick({
   slidesToShow: 3,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   asNavFor: '.slider-for',
   dots: true,
   centerMode: true,
   focusOnSelect: true
 });
```

In result I got something like this
[image]

What's wrong wrong with my code? Where I should add classes for slick slider? Thank you for any help!

Comment: Have you added script in document ready function?

Comment: Yes sir. Maybe it's something wrong with VC classes?

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Comment: Nope. It looks like everything is ok with code. I assume it could be class or something.